# Open Arena: Full screen option on; why lower slice of screen missing?

Tags: games, screen

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I first downloaded Open Arena it worked great but all of a sudden this happened--see screen shot:

[image: Open Arena with lower slice of screen missing]

The missing lower slice of screen is messing up an otherwise awesome game--I can barely see the lower buttons to continue or confirm between levels--I already have the full screen option checked--how do I fix this? Please help!